# Android: I want to hide progress bar after ListView selection changed

Tags: android, progress-bar

Due to the items contents in ListView are little bit complex, my ListView takes a few seconds to roll to the particular item. So I want to add a Indeterminate progress bar to make it smooth.

To rolling to a particular item, I used listView.setSelection(n) to do that. Then I tended to use "setOnItemSelectedListener" event handler to hide the progress bar after rolling. But the event handler doesn't get call.

May be my concept are totally wrong, I am no idea how to do that (progress bar using like this case). If you show me the concept more details are also welcome.

Thank you very much.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
boolean isProgressBarDone;

private void jumpToSelectedItem(View arg0) {
        ...
        listView.setSelection(selectedDaYunItem);
}

ListView listView = (ListView)((MyActivity)cellView.getContext()).findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        // onItemSelected event handler has not triggered.
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            isProgressBarDone = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
        }
});


public class LiouYunCellAdapter {

    cellView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        // It takes a little seconds to operate.
        private void jumpToSelectedItem(View arg0) {
            ....
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                progressBar = findProgressBar(arg0);

                // ProgressBar start.
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        isProgressBarDone = false;
                        while (!isProgressBarDone) {                                                
                            // Update the progress bar
                            progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });                                           
                        }                                                                               
                    }).start();

                    jumpToSelectedItem(arg0);  
                }               
            }

            return true;
        }
    });      
    // End setOnTouchListener().

}    
// end class LiouYunCellAdapter.
```

}

Comment: Can you post some of the code so we can help?

Comment: Ok. I have added code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I dont see you triggering anything onclick excpet for setting isProgressBarDone to true. What you need to do is use the fomat below (which you already have) but put your code to scroll in there. OnClick you will get the position of what was selected. Use that id to then trigger the scroll. You should also initate your progress bar here and end it at the conclusion of that method. Right now your progress bar is running on its own thread and I don't see anything to stop it.

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

            //You will get the positino of the item clicked here
            //This is where your code to scroll should go as well as
            //starting the progress bar
        }



});
```

Take a look at the example I linked to below. It deals with the use of a progressdialog while loading a custom list view but I think the concept is applicable to your code. What you need to do is fix when you call the progress bar and dismiss it.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: Thanks Rarw. Let me try it and report here later.